# Deer with strange growths

Tags: deer

I have a trailcam set up and curious what these growths are on this specific deer. I don't think it's Chronic Wasting Disease but unsure what it could be.

[image: Strange growths]

Comment: Ticks can be visible but the lumps look too big for ticks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that these will be [fibromas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deer_cutaneous_fibroma), likely caused by a papillomavirus, but could also be caused by a poxvirus.

Exactly which papillomavirus or poxvirus is dependent on the particular species of deer infected, as these viruses are often species-specific.

There are some resources about the diseases at [Maine.gov](https://www.maine.gov/ifw/fish-wildlife/wildlife/living-with-wildlife/diseases/deer-fibroma.html) and at the [National Deer Association](https://www.deerassociation.com/deer-warts-eat/)