# Deer - growth mass identification

Tags: deer

I was looking at my cellular trail camera and noticed this young doe with large mass growing on the front of her chest.

I've done some Googling but not convinced entirely it is infection or a contusion from an injury.

[image: doe with large mass on front of chest]

Comment: related, but not necessarily the same:  https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/27799/deer-with-strange-growths

Comment: Very hard to say from the image, too big to be a viral infection like in the comment from @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica. Could be a neoplasm (cancer) or abscess.